# i want to fill an array which his length is 20 with randomly number from 1 to 100 in python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

i want to **fill an array** which his length is 20 with *randomly* number from 1 to 100  in python

```
import numpy as np
a = np.empty(shape=5)
print(a)
for i in range(50){
    a[i]=randint(1,100);}
```

Comment: Do they have to be all different?

Comment: Why do you use `shape=5` and `range(50)` if the length should be 20? Shouldn't they both be 20?

Answer (score 1):

You can both create an array or fill an array with 20 random integers using `numpy.random.randint()`:

```
import numpy as np

# create an 20-element array of random integres in [1, 100]
a = np.random.randint(1, 101, size = 20)
print(a)

# create an uninitialized array of 20 integers 
b = np.empty(20, dtype = int)
# fill b with 20 random integers in [1, 100]
for i in range(len(b)):
    b[i] = np.random.randint(1, 101, size = 1)
print(b)
```

**Sample Output**:

```
# array a
[56 39 20 14 78 58 86 72 67 87 79 78 84 49 43 80 79 21 46 31]
# array b
[50 26 87 22  6 37 36 32 84 79 62  2 79 45 90 66 67 30 26 85]
```

In my code above:

- `numpy.random.randint(1, 101, size = 20)` ([documentation](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generated/numpy.random.randint.html#numpy.random.randint)) creates a 20-element array of random integers in the closed interval `[1, 100]`;
- `numpy.random.randint(1, 101, size = 1)` creates a scalar array (1-element) of a random integer in the closed interval `[1, 100]`. We generate 20 such random integers and assign each of them to a different element of the array `b` of integers.

Notes regarding your code:

- `a = np.empty(shape=5)` ([documentation](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.empty.html#numpy-empty)) creates an uninitialized array of `5` floats; if you need `20` elements, this should be `20`;
- if you need an array of integers, you should specify this using the `dtype` optional argument as I have done above. If you do not specify `dtype`, by default, you will be allocated an uninitialized array of floats.

Comment: @Alaa Aoun Does this answer your question or did you need something different?